# Does the Intel graphics 2500 support 1920×1080 @ 60Hz resolution over VGA?

Tags: resolution, vga, intel-core-i5

I have a PC having Gigabyte motherboard with an integrated Intel graphics 2500, with only a VGA port. I have searched the Intel product specification site, but I couldn't find any resolution mentioned there. So, I asked this question here.
Will it support 1920×1080 resolution @ 60Hz over VGA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this
[user testimony](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monitors/comments/1y7g28/max_resolutions_vga_vs_hdmi_vs_dvi/),
the maximum resolution of the Intel HD Graphics 2500 on VGA is 2048x1152,
but I don't know about the 60Hz.

If you are on Windows 10, you may find this out by right-click on the desktop,
select "Display settings", set your resolution under "Display resolution",
then click "Advanced display settings" and see what Hz value is displayed next to
"Refresh rate (Hz)".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally, I bought a full HD screen monitor and found that it worked even over VGA without any distortion or blur.